# Can we use vue-meta without SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, metadata, vue-meta

I've been working with [vue-meta npm package](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta) for updating my meta tags. But I see an issue that the value which I put inside `metaInfo()` is not rendered correctly in google search description.

```js
metaInfo () {
    return {
      title: 'FAQ',
      meta: [
        {name: 'description', content: 'How can we help you?'},
        {property: 'og:title', content: 'How can we help you?'},
        {property: 'og:site_name', content: 'FAQ site'},
        {property: 'og:description', content: 'How can we help you?'}
      ]
    }
  }
```

If we open devtools in browser, we can see the meta tags were appended in DOM. So we have two descriptions now.

1. The meta description which we put in `index.html` file.
2. The meta description which is appended in DOM with the help of the vue-meta package.

I been reading a lot about vue-meta and it hard for me to find a solution without using SSR or Nuxt, so that we could use `vue-meta` without using SSR.

Comment: So, what are your Nuxt settings: `target: static` and `ssr: false`? What is the issue with using SSR? The fact is that even if Google _can_ read the content generated by JS, it will not give a good score for something that needs to be parsed. If you want some real SEO boost, the only way of doing things is to go all-in and generate the pages in advance. To see what is available without your SPA, you can disable the JS and check the source code. Not sure what do you call `index.html` in the case of Nuxt. By reading your question again, it looks like you're currently running Vue in fact?

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your reply. I'm using only vue.js not using nuxt anywhere in my application. And it's a hug application so using nuxt will be a complete rewriting of the whole application. So I'm wondering is there anyother way we can update meta tags property with vue-meta without SSR. Because vue-meta without SSR is not working correctly.

Comment: Vue-meta has nothing to do with this. All it does is append/modify meta tags while you run your Vue app, and it's doing that correctly. Google search results doesn't run your Vue app, it just reads what's on your HTML page. Thus, either you need to include some basic meta tags in your index.html, and if it needs to have different meta content per page, you'll have to render the pages beforehand with SSR. There is no way to make google parse your runtime javascript code for your search results.

Comment: Actually, passing a Vue app into a Nuxt one is not that much of a work. You may maybe give it a try. You'll achieve it faster than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this kind of question needs to be asked at the beginning of a project (SSR or not) and usually leads to decide what to use.

Good thing is that Nuxt is not that different from Vue. Since it's just a wrapper on top of Vue, you can throw 90% of your current app in it and it should work pretty fine (had somebody do just that few months ago and it went super smoothly + was pretty fast). Nuxt don't have a lot of drawbacks and essentially add nice things on top of Vue.

You could also give a try to this: https://prerender.io/vue-js/ (it does support SPAs)
But IMO, you'll get more control and flexibility with Nuxt with SSR (either in `static` or `server` target).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct you should use nuxtjs if you want meta tags. I was facing the same problem as the site was already built but client demanded he need meta tags also. So instead of migrating the whole site to nuxtjs, I decided to use index.php instead of index.html . Now I can add meta tags based on page type without migrating the whole project to nuxtjs.

suppose your index.html after building the project page looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
    <link href="/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/fonts/Edustdy.whtt" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont3e6e.eot" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>default title</title>

    <link href="/css/course.1d10f9e6.css" rel="prefetch">
    <link href="/js/about.b5c0f3ce.js" rel="prefetch">
    <link href="/js/course.d8d75b7d.js" rel="prefetch">
    <link href="/css/app.203f8281.css" rel="preload" as="style">
    <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.e8860705.css" rel="preload" as="style">
    <link href="/js/app.c39400af.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="/js/chunk-vendors.4cc0d445.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.e8860705.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/app.203f8281.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but this site doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
            continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/js/chunk-vendors.4cc0d445.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.c39400af.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My requirement was to get the meta from API for a particular page only, so the index.php would look something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
<?php

 $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode('/',$current_url);
if($url[1] == 'course'){
    $response =  shell_exec("curl yourapi.com/course/find?slug=$url[2]");
    $decoded = json_decode($response ,true);
} 
?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <?php 
    if(!$decoded['courseName']){
        $decoded['courseName'] = "default title";
    }
    ?>
    <meta name="title" content='<?php echo $decoded['courseName'] ?>'>
      <meta name="description" content='<?php echo $decoded['snippet']?>'>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://yoursite.com/<?php echo $current_url?>">
      <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $decoded['courseName']?>">
      <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $decoded['snippet']?>">
      <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $decoded['thumbnail'] ?>">
      <meta property="og:image:width" content="800" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
    <meta itemprop="name">
    <meta property="og:title">
    <meta name="twitter:title">
    <meta name="description">
    <meta itemprop="description">
    <meta property="og:description">
    <meta name="twitter:description">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/Edustdy.whtt">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont3e6e.eot">

    <title>default title</title>

    <link href="/css/course.1d10f9e6.css" rel="prefetch">
    <link href="/js/about.b5c0f3ce.js" rel="prefetch">
    <link href="/js/course.d8d75b7d.js" rel="prefetch">
    <link href="/css/app.203f8281.css" rel="preload" as="style">
    <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.e8860705.css" rel="preload" as="style">
    <link href="/js/app.c39400af.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="/js/chunk-vendors.4cc0d445.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.e8860705.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/app.203f8281.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but this site doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
            continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/js/chunk-vendors.4cc0d445.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.c39400af.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now meta tags will be available on google, Facebook, Whatsapp, etc but as you are using PHP there might be some security issues that you need to consider as I only did this by sending 30 minutes in PHP.

Comment: One of the benefits of Nuxt is to be able to host it on a static platform with no fees tho. Here, you need to have a running backend server.

Comment: Agree nuxt is by far superior than any of this. But you have to configure your webpack auth etc. I used this as I had tight deadline and didn't want migrate to nuxt. You can consider as somewhat lazy approach to add meta.